# Wordpress - Waypoint Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I dowloaded a HTML, CSS, JS website template to create a wordpress theme.

I donwnload wordpress/scripts to bundle all asset files into two: index.css and index.js

Here is my entry index.js:

`

```
import "./sass/main.scss";
import "./js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js";
import "./js/popper.min.js";
import "./js/bootstrap.min.js";
import "./js/swiper-bundle.min.js";
import "./js/waypoints.min.js";
import "./js/jquery.counterup.min.js";
import "./js/isotope.pkgd.min.js";
import "./js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js";
import "./js/wow.min.js";
import "./js/custom.js";
```

`

After running *npm start* the *wordpress/scripts* creates a build folder with *index.css ad index.js*.

Inside ***functions.php*** and enequeue index.css and index.js.

Inside the *front-page.php* i passed all the contents of the original html template.

And it is throwing an error on console:

`

```
waypoints.min.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'each')
    at waypoints.min.js:7
    at Object../src/js/waypoints.min.js (waypoints.min.js:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at make namespace object:7
    at index.js:10
    at index.js:10
```

`

Inspecting the error line:

`

```
e.each(["innerHeight","innerWidth","off","offset","on","outerHeight","outerWidth","scrollLeft","scrollTop"],function(e,i){t.prototype[i]=function(){var t=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);return this.$elemen
```

`
(Since its minified i cannot show all the code)

When i open the original html file on the browser, it works perfectly. Only when i try to use in wordpress.

What may be the cause?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figure a way.
I loaded all scripts using cdn.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).